# ASP.NET MVC return JSON() does show me a Save file Dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am new on the .NET MVC pattern and tried to call a Action using `AJAX.BeginForm` Helper Class in my Controller I return seralized JSON using return JSON();

In my view I Added a Scrip witch should consume the returnes JSON.

```
   function ResultSet(request) {

   var json = content.get_response().get_object();
   var result = eval(json);

   if (result.Successfull) {
       alert("Success!");
   }
   else {
       alert("else");
       }
   }
```

But instead if I am returned the Browser Shows me a Save Dialog to Save the JSON file.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar problem, try making sure you added the references to the microsoft ajax libraries:

```
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

also. your ResultSet() method takes a variable named "request" as parameter, I think it should be called "content", like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ResultSet(content) {
        var json = content.get_response().get_object();

        var result = eval(json);
        if (result.Successfull) {
            alert("Success!");
        }
        else {
            alert("else");
        }
    }    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting *content type* of response to **application/json** as follows:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/json";
```

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to reference jQuery. Put this inside the head of your html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```